# Should there be an Apple logo on the hard drive of a MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, kernel-panic

I was installing an update on my MacBook Pro mid 2012 when it crashed. Kernel Panic. I brought it to an authorized service center for repair. The following day, I got a call that the center is refusing to repair my laptop because when they opened it, apparently there was no Apple logo on the hard drive. Hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

There should be. Many, if not all, MacBooks have in fact shipped with hard drives with Apple logos on them.

Comment: What to do then? It was bought from the Apple Store. The serial number was even verified to check its warranty.

Comment: I'm not sure what "Many, if not all" means.  I would be surprised if a non-reconditioned Mac from Apple had a drive without a sticker.  If you're sure the computer hasn't been repaired since you bought it, you might to ask Apple or the store to look into it.  Ask for an email or written note about the problem as they see it.